# Как получить содержимое подстроки без регулярных выражений

Tags: c#

Есть строка.

```
"name":"dog"
```

Самый простой вариант вытащить из него то что идет после `name` сделать регулярку

```
(?<=name":").+?(?=")
```

Все в принципе работает, однако файл большой и регулярки очень замедляют скорость. Есть ли альтернативы для данной операции?

Comment: у вас видимо json завёлся. Можете посмотреть в этом направлении

Comment: Json десериализовать очень затратная операция, так как он большого размера. Проще сделать как есть

Comment: Насколько большого ?

Comment: Разбор сложных языков, наподобие JSON, регулярками, или ещё хуже того, ручной — всегда плохая идея.

Comment: Если у вас огромный файл, а вам нужно извлечь лишь часть информации, [попробуйте `JsonTextReader`](http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/parsing-big-records-with-jsonnet/240165316).

Comment: Несколько ускорить регулярку можно параметром `RegexOptions.Compiled`. Но проще и быстрее использовать `line.Substring(8).TrimEnd('\"')` или `line.Substring(8, line.Length - 9)`. Последний вариант, вроде, быстрее (и генерирует меньше мусора).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ручной разбор сложных форматов — не самая простая штука. У вас может быть море проблем. Навскидку: пробелы? комментарии? строковые константы? разные типы кавычек? Вы ведь не хотите всё это предусматривать самостоятельно? Поэтому имеет смысл пользоваться готовым парсером, например, JSON.NET.

Если разбор всего файла в память — слишком дорогая операция, то вы можете вместо этого разбирать его токены в потоковом режиме. Вот вам пример того, как вытащить все значения строковых атрибутов `name`:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string json = "{ 'everything' : [ " +
                "{ 'name': 'dog' }, " +
                "{ 'trap': '\"name\" : \"snake\"' }, " +
                "{ \"name\"     : \"elephant\"}]}";
        // вам нужен будет, скорее всего, не StringReader, а StreamReader
        using (TextReader sr = new StringReader(json))
        {
            foreach (var name in ExtractNames(sr))
                Console.WriteLine(name);
        }
    }

    static IEnumerable<string> ExtractNames(TextReader tr)
    {
        using (var jsr = new JsonTextReader(tr))
        {
            bool expectValue = false;
            while (jsr.Read())
            {
                if (jsr.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment)
                    continue;
                if (expectValue)
                {
                    if (jsr.ValueType == typeof(string))
                        yield return (string)jsr.Value;
                    expectValue = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (jsr.TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName &&
                        (string)jsr.Value == "name")
                        expectValue = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: а если свойство Name будет у объекта со свойством name? например: `{ 'name': { 'name': { 'name': 'dog' } } }` все три будут выведены?

Comment: @Grundy: Не-а, берутся только значения-строки. `if (jsr.ValueType == typeof(string)) ...`

Comment: ага, то есть вернет только внутренний? а на саму вложенность ограничения нет ведь?

Comment: @Grundy: Ага, только внутренний. Оно смотрит просто пару токенов «имя атрибута»/«начало значения атрибута», так что с вложенностью проблем быть не должно.

Comment: _нет_ - это на какой вопрос ответ? :-D успел отредактировать!

Comment: @Grundy: «Нет» уже нету :)

Comment: я все видел!!!!

Comment: Тогда оно было ответом на вопрос о вложенности :)